# Sens of running threaded function to check the condition every 1h ? DJANGO

Tags: django

i was wondering if there is a sens of running special function on spearate thread to check the specific query. If return is true then delete it. I'm not sure if this is the way to deal with things like that in django. I'm working on cinema online booking and i want to delete all objects of booking if have not been confirmed until 30min before movie starts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think [Celery](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html) is what you are looking for. You can create a task and run it with Celery worker in background. For Celery > 2.0 this can be something like:

**celery.py**

```
from celery.schedules import crontab

app.conf.beat_schedule = {
    # Executes every 30 mins
    'run-every-30-mins': {
        'task': 'tasks.rec_delete',
        'schedule': crontab(minute='*/30'),
        'args': (),
    },
}
```

**tasks.py**

```
import celery   

from portal.models import MyModel

@celery.task 
def rec_delete():
    MyModel.objects.filter(some_condition=True).delete()
```

Read about periodic tasks [here](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html).

Comment: Thanks ! :) I believe this is what I was looking for.